# Xcode problem - Provisioning profile failed qualification

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

Xcode problem - Provisioning profile failed qualification.

I want to upload the new version to the appstore.

I have already removed all certificates from the keychain and created new ones .. nothing works

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Which version of Xcode are you using? Did you get a chance to figure out what was happening or fix the issue?

Comment: Facing the same issue I think it is because of Big Sur OS.